# Excel: text to columns is remembered, how to disable?

Tags: excel, text, excel-2010, multiple-columns, pasting

I have text copied from a pdf file to Excel(2010). I used 'text-to-columns' to create separate columns.

Now I have finished that part of my task, I want to paste another piece of text into the same file.

But now Excel directly uses the text-to-columns I used to split this new text, which I now (obvious) do not want to be split.
I tried pasting the text on a new worksheet. I tried to paste this text in a new workbook, but still the text is directly split by excel.

I tried pasting as text and I tried pasting as Unicode text. But so far, I have not found the solution for this. How can I make Excel "forget" that it has split text into columns?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Select any cell with a value and run Data ► Text-to-Columns, Delimited. Turn off **all** delimiters and click Finish.

[image: Text-to-Columns delimited, none]

Subsequent pasting of information into a worksheet will not use 'remembered' delimiters since there are none.